# wpf textblock won't display scrollbar inside tabcontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollbar

I've got a tabcontrol with textblock.  Nothing I do seems to get the vertical scrollbar to work.   I've tried it with a stackpanel; then using just the scrollviewer options inside the textblock instead of outside.  Weirdly the horizontal scrollbar works fine.  This shows the vertical scrollbar but it's not enabled.  If I set both to Auto, then the vertical scroll doesn't even show, even when the text is longer than the control.

```
<TabItem Header="Item Description" FontSize="14" FontWeight="DemiBold">
    <DockPanel>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItemText}" Padding="5" FontSize="14" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="100"  MinHeight="100"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DockPanel>
</TabItem>
```

Visual Studio 2017, wpf, mvvm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the `ScrollViewer` and the `TextBlock` with a readonly `TextBox`:

```
<TabItem Header="Item Description" FontSize="14" FontWeight="DemiBold">
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItemText, Mode=OneWay}"
                             TextWrapping="Wrap"
                             Padding="5" FontSize="14"
                             IsReadOnly="True"
                             BorderThickness="0"
                             Height="100"
                             MinHeight="100"
                             AcceptsReturn="True"
                             SelectionBrush="{x:Null}"
                             Cursor="Arrow"
                             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
    </DockPanel>
</TabItem>
```

Comment: Well, doesn't work entirely.  With the Height set in there, the component won't expand to fit available space.  Without the height in there, it expands beyond the available space and gets chopped off, with or without the VerticalAlignment set to "Stretch".  But this is far better than before.

Comment: Woot! (again)  Finally figured it out.  I had the tabcontrol inside of a stackpanel, and didn't even notice.  So it was allowing the tabcontrol to be as large as needed.  Even though I had the actual control in a dockpanel, the outer stackpanel was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have enabled horizontal scrolling in the `ScrollViewer`. This means the text in `TextBlock` will never wrap because its parent container has given it infinite width to grow horizontally. Try setting `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` to `Disabled` - this will force the textblock to wrap when it runs out of room horizontally. Once the text grows beyond the vertical limits of the `ScrollViewer` the vertical scroll bar will become visible if `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` is set to `Auto` or become enabled if the `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` is set to `Visible`.

Comment: thanks for your response.  Unfortunately that didn't help.  I removed the text wrap option now because I actually don't want it to wrap.  I set the VerticalScrollBarVisibility to Auto also but that didn't help either.

Comment: @Jim I notice you also explicitly set your `TextBox`'s height. It will never grow vertically and therefore never exceed the height of your `ScrollViewer`.

Comment: Jason, thanks for your response.  Unfortunately that didn't help.  I removed the text wrap option now because I actually don't want it to wrap.  The wrap was an oversight.  I set the VerticalScrollBarVisibility to Auto also but that didn't help either.  The text involved is actually code, so it's multiple lines of text.  The first few lines display but below the bottom of the field they are all cut off.

Comment: Jason, I removed the height option from the textbox.  The scrollbar doesn't work and now the textbox bottom border is cutoff.  So it's growing but too big.